# Need a product name behalf of previous cost

Tags: sql

Anyone can help me to write a query.

Here I need filter based on cost if latest cost is greater than or less than previous cost

then I want to select product.

1. Product

   | **id** | **product** |
   | --- | --- |
   | 1 | A |
   | 2 | B |
   | 3 | C |
2. Order

   | **id** | **order_id** | **cost** | **order_date** |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | 1 | 4 | 10 | 15-04-2020:14:20 |
   | 2 | 5 | 20 | 15-04-2020:14:20 |
   | 1 | 6 | 20 | 15-04-2020:14:21 |
   | 3 | 7 | 30 | 15-04-2020:14:21 |
   | 3 | 8 | 25 | 15-04-2020:14:20 |
   | 2 | 9 | 15 | 15-04-2020:14:22 |
   | 3 | 10 | 30 | 15-04-2020:14:25 |
3. Result

| **id** | **product** |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |

I need a query of that problem.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: Please don't use table name as order;
It's a reserved keyword.
Also, Please have practice of having different column names than the table name.
Your `product` table has `product` column

Comment: Also,
Your expected result should be same as your `product` table;
As I see variation in cost of all three products

Comment: Another question; It may not matter;
I see; all order_dates are same. Only the time is different (Slightly varying). I wonder; How fast the prices changed for items;
OR
is this a typo and you were suppose to give different dates

Comment: @Shiv Can you tag the right database among mysql and postgresql ?

These were the two databases tagged originally in the post

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use table name as `order`;

It's a reserved keyword in sql. Also, Please have practice of having different column names than the table name. Your `product` table has `product` column.

I have changed the table name order to `order_table`.

**Also, Your expected result should be same as your product table; As I see variation in cost of all three products over time**

As you had tagged mysql and postgresql in the question;
I am providing you solution for both.

[The following query shall work in mysql](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae259b/6)

```
select distinct p1.id, p1.product
from product p1
inner join order_table o1 on p1.id = o1.id
inner join order_table o2 on p1.id = o2.id and o2.order_date > o1.order_date
where o1.cost <> o2.cost;
```

It shall give you the following result.

| **id** | **product** |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |

**[The above query shall also work in postgresql.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ae259/2)**

You just have to add `order by` clause to display results in expected order.

```
select distinct p1.id, p1.product
    from product p1
    inner join order_table o1 on p1.id = o1.id
    inner join order_table o2 on p1.id = o2.id and o2.order_date > o1.order_date
    where o1.cost <> o2.cost
    order by p1.id;
```

This also should give the expected result as:
It shall give you the following result.

| **id** | **product** |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |

Answer (score 0):

Use the `row_number` function to get the latest (where rn =1) and previous cost (where rn =2), then aggregate with a having clause that checks if the cost `where rn = 1` is not equal to the cost `where rn = 2`.

```
select P.id, P.product
from Products P join
(
  select id
  from 
  (
    select *, 
      row_number() over (partition by id order by order_date desc) rn
    from Orders
  ) t
 group by id
 having max(case rn when 1 then cost end) <> max(case rn when 2 then cost end)
) O
on P.id = O.id
order by P.id
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Jvm-ZB1m)